# How can I extract multiple elements from a column matrix (Python)?

Tags: python, matrix

Say if I have a column matrix

```
n =  
[[0.649100404993098]
 [0.548818798116734]
 [-0.526750976336541]]
```

I want to assign the values of n to x,y and z. For example `x= 0.649100404993098, y=0.548818798116734, z=-0.526750976336541`. If I do `x,y,z =n`, then they are assigned as a list with desired values. How can I directly assign the values to x,y and z? Thanks:)

PS: The code I'm running is

```
b= 9.166801286935154 ,c= 7.750592706723353 ,d= -7.438943945547988
sig = np.matrix([[b],[c],[d]])
n = np.dot(1/sqrt(b**2+c**2+d**2),sig)
nx, ny, nz = [i for i in n]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this if you're sure that the length of each element is 1:

```py
nx, ny, nz = [i.item() for i in n]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with:

```py
x, y, z = [i[0] for i in n]
```

If you have more than one column you could make it `i[j]` where j is the column index.